# Content script not listening to message event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am developing my first browser extension for my website.

What this extension should basically do is to have a browser action which opens a pop-up where you can edit specific cookie values for the current page.

However, cookie A can exist on the page `/` while cookie B can exist on the page `/checkout`. So I don't want to list every cookie inside the pop-up, only the one which is active on the current page.

So, I searched the documentation and found that in order to communicate between web page and add-on you have to use the message system as described here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Communicating_with_the_web_page

To do so, my website has a JavaScript file which is loaded on every page. In this JavaScript I'm executing the following code

`window.postMessage({type: 'FROM_PAGE', data: visibleCookies}, '*');`

This piece of code is definitely executed, because I put a `console.log` before or after that statement, I can see that it's being logged.

Now, in my content script I want to listen to this by executing the following code

```
// experimentManager.js
console.log('testd');
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    if (event.source !== window) {
        return;
    }
});
```

However, the `console.log(event);` is never executed. The listener is never activated. When I press the browser action so that the popup opens `testd` is logged into console, but still, the listener doesn't get any events. It's just not getting executed.

I don't know which files are relevant, but this is my `manifest.json`

```
// manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My first addon",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "My first addon description",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon.png",
    "default_title": "My first addon",
    "default_popup": "popup/manage_experiment.html",
    "browser_style": true
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "cookies",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.mydomain/*"],
      "js": ["experimentManager.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

And inside the pop-up script I'm executing this code among other things

```
browser.tabs.executeScript({file: "/content_scripts/experimentManager.js"})
    .then(manageExperiments)
    .catch(handleError);
```

which is probably the reason why the `console.log('testd')` gets executed, but nothing else?

What am I missing?

Comment: 1) There's no need to communicate with the web page here AFAICT. You need to communicate with your content script which is done via [runtime API messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). 2) Declaring content_scripts injects the scripts so there's no need for executeScript. 3) There's probably no need for content scripts altogether as you can use chrome.cookies API to manage the cookies.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. 1.) There is, because let's say you are on `/` and cookie `A` is written to your browser, then you visit `/checkout`, cookie `A` will still be in your browser, but shouldn't be managed through the extension. You shall be able to make changes to cookies, but only a selected number of cookies shall be managable, even if you have more in the browser. 2.) The reason I do this, is because on domains other than mine the error callback (see `catch`) would be called, and then I can display "This add-on does not work here".

Comment: 3.) Yes, and I'm already using the `cookies` API to edit or retrieve cookie values, but as said in my previous reply I only want to show a select number of cookies inside the add-on which will be decided by the page, that's why I need this page communication. I mean, let's not talk about HOW it shall be implemented, the problem is the same: I can't communicate from my page-script to the content-script

Comment: I don't see how you run the page script so I can only guess it's a timing issue.

Comment: Do you think the page-script get's executed too early or too late? Right now, the script is included at the end of the body, and, because we still have some jQuery fragments in it, it's also inside  `$(document).ready(() => {`

Comment: I think the page script sends the message before your content script runs which occurs by default at document_idle that is after the page scripts has processed DOMContentLoaded or jQuery.ready()

Comment: Okay, so what I tried now is to not send the message directly, but only after a user clicked an element, so that way I can be sure that my page has been loaded. However, even if I wait 5 seconds and only then press the button which sends the message, I still don't get any `console.logs` regarding the event :/

Comment: Hard to say without running the extension so I suggest debugging it in devtools by setting breakpoints in the page script e.g. by using `debugger` statement and inspecting DOM/whatever.

Comment: Hm, this is a good hint. Because I don't see the content_script in the list of JavaScript files, so it feels like the script is not even loaded. When I open the debugger, I can see the files for my other extensions, such as uBlock, bitwarden etc. so it seems like this already could be the issue, right?

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction @wOxxOm. The path to the content script was wrong, I had a typo. Therefore it was never loaded on page load, but only when opening the pop-up. I feel stupid, but thanks :D